# How can store Input type Number length 17 digits number

Tags: javascript, html

```
<pre><input type="number" class="quantity"  value=""/></pre>
```

How can store ISD phone which is long to be 17 digit, input type number use because in native open keyboard only numeric value enter. so how change 
max = floating-point number.

Comment: Use a string. It isn’t meaningful to treat phone numbers as integers most of the time.

Comment: After actually seeing your HTML: don’t use an `<input type="number">` for a phone number. Use an `<input type="tel">`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a number type to store a phone number:

1. They are not really numbers, e.g. it makes no sense to "add" two different phone numbers.
2. Leading zeros are important in phone numbers.

Use a string type instead, and validate appropriately.